# Flutter | TextField - How to create RegExp for valid double?

Tags: regex, flutter, textfield

FilteringTextInputFormatter - How to create RegExp to prevent the user from typing more than one period, from typing a comma, from typing numbers after zero except period, etc.

Comment: FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'(^\d*\.?\d*)')) works but with some flaw.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Enter a number:',
                      ),
                      keyboardType:
                          TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      inputFormatters: [
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter(
                            RegExp(r'^\d*\.?\d{0,1}$'),
                            allow: true),
                      ],
                    ),
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

```
List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormatters = [
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
    RegExp(r'(^\d*\.?\d*)'),
  ),

  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
    RegExp(r'\.\.+'), 
    replacementString: '.',
  ),

  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
    RegExp(r'^\.'), 
    replacementString: '0.',
  ),

  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
    RegExp(r'\d+-'), 
  ),

  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
    RegExp(r'\.-'),
    replacementString: '.',
  ),

  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
    RegExp(r'-\.+'),
  ),

  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
    RegExp(r'^0\d+'),
    replacementString: '0.',
  ),
];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).